# Using IIS with Visual Studio 2019 and ASP.NET CORE 3.1

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, iis

I am running local IIS, and using vs.net 2019 to build web application. All is up and running when I debug-run.

The question/problem quite simply: when I want to modify the cshtml or the enclosed javascript right now I need to restart the web application pushing F5 again.  Is there a way I can modify the js/cshtml and just refresh the browser?  (this was the workflow I used with .net framework)

Comment: think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52204892/reload-asp-net-core-app-when-dll-files-change-bin-deploy - not built into kestrel server

Comment: This may be working ..trying now https://dev.to/expertsinside/turn-on-runtime-compilation-for-modified-views-in-asp-net-core-fbp

Comment: Do you mean you use visual studio to remote debug the IIS application or directly debug the application by modifying the VS launch settings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use 'dotnet watch'. Open Package manager console and **navigate to your project** folder. Then **run 'dotnet watch run'**. you can go to browser and **visit localhost:5000 (port depends on your configuration)** than you will see the app is running. When you change something on cshtml or js file, **refreshing the page** will reflect the changes to page.